# Succinct array datastracture

Tags: arrays, succinct-data-structures

Is it true that there is no known succinct data structure that has integer array (vector) functionality? Desirable operations would be:

- append O(1)
- access(i) - returns i-th item O(1)
- iterate(i..j) - i.e. iterate from i to j efficiently O(j-i)

The emphasis is on **integer** arrays and O(1). A structure that divides the array into large blocks that are individually compressed would not fit the criteria.

Comment: Lists in Python do that, but in amortized $\mathcal{O}(1)$, not worst case.

Comment: Lists in python are not succinct in the "succinct data structure" sense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I missed that point.